# Reading/writing txt strings

Tags: c, string, file

I'm trying to learn how to manipulate txt files in C at the moment. This program should read in population.txt (http://pastebin.com/Q5fNRuJG), find the highest population and display it, make a file with populations of greater than 1 million, make a file with all the irish cities, and print the total population. It only creates empty files, and prints the total population (now also prints most populous city). Can anyone help?

The program (compiled in Borland):

```
//Program that filters and processes data with fscanf()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *ireland;
    FILE *mmplus;
    int pop;
    int highest_pop=0;
    char country[50];
    char city[50];
    int total_pop=0;

    fp = fopen("population.txt","r");
    ireland = fopen("ireland_pop.txt","w");
    mmplus = fopen("greater_than_1MM.txt","w");

    //Checking if the file opened correctly
    if (fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }//End if

    //Scanning fp row by row
    while (fscanf(fp, "%s" "%s" "%i", country, city , &pop) != EOF)
    {
        //Getting the total population
        total_pop=total_pop+pop;

        //Storing the highest pop
        if (pop > highest_pop)
        {
            highest_pop=pop;
        }//End if

        //Finding 1 million+ cities
        if(pop>=1000000)
        {
            fprintf(mmplus,"%s %s %d\n",country,city,pop);
        }//End if

        //If the city is in Ireland
        if (strcmp("ireland",country) == 0)
        {
            fprintf(ireland,"%s %s %d\n",country,city,pop);
        }//End if
    }//End while

    rewind(fp); //Fix 1

    while (fscanf(fp, "%s" "%s" "%d", country, city , &pop) != EOF)
    {
        //Finding the city with the highest population
        if (pop == highest_pop)
        {
            printf("The city with the highest population is %s, %s, with a population of %d",city, country, pop);
        }//End if
    }//end while

    printf("The total population of all the cities is %d.",total_pop);
    getchar();
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ireland);
    fclose(mmplus);
}
```

Comment: `rewind` before 2nd while-loop.

Comment: So? What is the difficulty you are facing?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY , That is a perfectly valid answer. That will solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @CoolGuy OP's problem that _It only creates empty files_ It's inexplicable phenomenon.

Comment: The rewind fixed the printing highest pop, thanks.

It's still only creating empty files, though.

Comment: Should you be using the case-insensitive string comparison `stricmp("ireland",country)`?

Comment: @WeatherVane All the characters in population.txt are lowercase. I tried it anyway, still didn't work.

Comment: when compiling, need to turnon all the warnings, so such erroneous lines as 'main()' are flagged.  Should be: 'int main()'  and end of main() needs a 'return(0);' statement

Comment: @user3629249 I used Weather Vane's fix below, then compiled it without int main() and return 0; and just used main(), and it still works fine.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Why would `rewind` fix the problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig Can not be read at 2nd while-loop to have reached the end of the file in the 1st while-loop. `rewind` to reset the reading position at the beginning of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time I ran your program I got empty files. The second time I ran it I got correct output. The third time I got one correct file and one incorrect file.

I *think* I may have typed `ctrl-C` to end the program. So I made a couple of changes to the last few lines of the program - adding `newline` to the output, and closing the files before waiting for input. After that, it works every time, but I can't explain everything.

```
fclose(fp);
fclose(ireland);
fclose(mmplus);
printf("The total population of all the cities is %d.\n",total_pop);
getchar();
return 0;
```

Comment: Yes! That worked perfectly! Thanks, it's been destroying me for a couple hours now.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to implement the algorithm

```
//note: the system function: perror()
//      outputs the strerror() message,
//      the first parameter text, etc

//Program that filters and processes data with fgets() and sscanf()
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> // strcpy(), strlen()
#include <unistd.h> // unlink()

int main()
{
    FILE *fp      = NULL; // input
    FILE *ireland = NULL; // list irish cities
    FILE *mmplus  = NULL; // list cities > 1million population

    int pop;
    char country[50];
    char city[50];

    int total_pop=0;
    int  maxPopulation = 0;
    char maxPopulationCity[50] = {'\0'};
    char maxPopulationCountry[50] = {'\0'};

    char buffer[200]; // input work area


    if( NULL == (fp = fopen("population.txt","r") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for population.txt failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (ireland = fopen("ireland_pop.txt","w") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for ireland_pop.txt failed" );
        fclose(fp); // cleanup
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    if( NULL == (mmplus = fopen("greater_than_1MM.txt","w") ) )
    { // then, fopen failed
        perror( "fopen for greater_than_1MM.txt failed" );
        fclose(fp); // cleanup
        fclose(ireland);
        unlink("ireland_pop.txt");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful


    //Scanning fp row by row
    while ( fgets( buffer, sizeof buffer, fp ) )
    {
        // this code makes the following assumptions
        // 1) city is all one word
        //    (I.E, no 'st paul'
        // 2) country is all one word and 'ireland' is always lower case
        //    (I.E. no 'Ireland' and no 'United States'
        // 3) pop contains no ',' and is always positive
        // 4) data item delimiters are only ' ', \t

        if( 3 != sscanf(buffer, " %s %s %i", country, city , &pop) )
        {
            //calculate the total population
            total_pop += pop;

            //Storing the highest pop found so far
            if (pop >maxPopulation)
            {
                maxPopulation=pop; // save new largest population
                strcpy( maxPopulationCity, city ); // save new city
                strcpy( maxPopulationCountry, country ); // save new country
            }//End if

            //Finding 1 million+ cities
            if(pop>=1000000)
            {
                fprintf(mmplus,"%s %s %d\n",country,city,pop);
            }//End if

            //If the city is in Ireland
            if (strcmp("ireland",country) == 0)
            {
                fprintf(ireland,"%s %s %d\n",country,city,pop);
            }//End if

            if( buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] != '\n' )
            { // then, input line to long for buffer[]
                // read chars until newline consumed
                while( '\n' != getchar() ) ;
            }// end if
        } // end if
    }//End while

    printf("The city with the highest population is %s, %s, with a population of %d",
           maxPopulationCity,
           maxPopulationCountry,
           maxPopulation);

    printf("The total population of all the cities is %d.",total_pop);
    getchar();

    fclose(fp);
    fclose(ireland);
    fclose(mmplus);
    return(0);
} // end function: main
```